# Power BI - 1 visual, with 2 measures filtered by separate slicers

Tags: powerbi

I have 1 idea, but was not able to implement in reality.

So I have a table - Zone average.
And Fields
Zone - geo zone
Categories - 15 diffent categories
Score - %
Market - basically country

Table structure

| Zone | Categories | Score | Market |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AOA | Cat 1 | 5.0% | Austria |
| Europe | Cat 2 | 66.0% | Hungary |

So, what I want to achieve is to have 1 visual, that will show average by Zone and average by Market. So i can see how market perform vs zone. But here is the catch. I want to have 2 slicers 1 that will filter Zone and 1 that will filter Market - separately. Lowest level of detail - Categories and categories will be in the visual too.

Comment: Add your sample output.

Comment: Hi, a little confused with your question. Do you mean one visual contains Zone, Market and Categories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ALL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/all-function-dax) function, your meseares should be like this:

```
Score by zone = CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Table'[Score]),ALL('Table'[Market]))
Score by Market = CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Table'[Score]),ALL('Table'[Zone]))
```

Keep in mind Score should be a decimal or percetage, not a text

Comment: Thanks man, this is working well. Sometimes the easiest way is the best :)